# Merge two dataframes with different timestamps

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have two dataframes:

df1 =

| Time | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 19:43:58:428 | 10 | 2 | 3 |
| 19:44:07:777 | 5 | 1.5 | -2 |

df2 =

| Time | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 19:43:58:372 | 2.154 | 3.5 |
| 19:43:58:872 | 3.14 | 1.3 |
| 19:44:07:372 | 1.4 | 2 |
| 19:44:07:872 | 1.76 | 2.2 |
| 19:44:07:910 | 1.43 | 2.43 |

I have to combine these dataframes, such that the time of df2 is closest to time of df1. So the resultant df will be:

df_result =

| Time | A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 19:43:58:428 | 10 | 2 | 3 | 2.154 | 3.5 |
| 19:44:07:777 | 5 | 1.5 | -2 | 1.76 | 2.2 |

How to do it using pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`pandas.merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25.0/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html), pass `nearest` to the direction parameter, it will merge based on the smallest difference.

```py
df1['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Time'], format='%H:%M:%S:%f')
df2['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Time'], format='%H:%M:%S:%f')

pd.merge_asof(df1, df2, on='Time', direction='nearest')
```

**OUTPUT:**

```py
                     Time   A    B  C      D    E
0 1900-01-01 19:43:58.428  10  2.0  3  2.154  3.5
1 1900-01-01 19:44:07.777   5  1.5 -2  1.760  2.2
```

You can convert the Time column back to the previous format, using `strftime('%H:%M:%S:%f')`

**PS:** `merge_asof` requires the keys in the dataframe to be sorted, you may want to sort the keys before merging.

Comment: Actually I have a quiet big dataframe. I am doing the way you've answered however, I am getting a "ValueError: right keys must be sorted" error.

Comment: Yeah, `merge_asof` requires the keys to be sorted. Try: `pd.merge_asof(df1.sort_values(['Time']), df2.sort_values['Time'], on='Time', direction='nearest')`

Comment: Can you edit code above to convert Time column back to previous format. I am using df_result['Time'] = df_result['Time'].dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S:%f'), but no success.

Comment: Are you getting any error while trying that? @Avinash

Comment: No, i am not getting any error. But the time is showing like "1900-01-01 19:43:58.428000".

Comment: @Avinash, I tested it twice and it is working fine, but if you are still having  the issue the probable reason might be due to different pandas and python version. You can try asking that question separately on Stackoverlfow Why `strftime` is not working.